# Convert long int* to long long int*

Tags: c++, c++11

On my platform, both long int and long long int are the same (64 bits). I have a pointer to a long int and I want to convert it to a pointer to a long long int. The following code

```
static_cast<long long int*>(pointer);
```

is not allowed. What is the correct way to do that in C++11?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to force 're-interpretation' of pointer:

```
reinterpret_cast<long long int*>(pointer);
```

Such cast means to compiler "stop checking, I know how better interpret binary data in that expression". So whenever making `reinterpret_cast` - check twice your knowledge of platform, memory alignment etc. Write some simple unit tests etc, run them through valgrind or address sanitizer.

So think now, if you really need to cast such pointer. Often redesign of function etc. can resolve such issue (for example if you only need data from pointed value - store it in some additional variable etc.).

You can also try to force a little bit checking by compiler:

```
template <typename Dest, typename Src>
Dest* safe_pointer_cast(Src* src)
{
  static_assert(sizeof(Src) == sizeof(Dest), "size of pointed values differ");
  static_assert(alignof(Src) == alignof(Dest), "alignment different");
  return reinterpret_cast<Dest*>(src);
}
```

Comment: It is a nice solution. But the compiler knows that long int and long long int are the same on my platform. Isn't there a "secure" way of doing it. I was expecting a "cast" that compiles only if long int and long long int are the same on the platform.

Comment: you can always use `static_assert` to ensure they're of same size

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, but I was expecting something more "integrated" in the langage. It might not exist.

Comment: as it is by definition not safe, language forces programmer to be explicit and makes him/her think twice :)

Comment: The compiler knows if it is safe (long int and long long int are the same) or it is not. I have a C library (Intel MKL) that takes a pointer to a long long int, and I want to use the same kind of integer everywhere on my program (I use std::ptrdiff_t which is long int of my platform). I'll implement it with a static_assert.

Comment: @InsideLoop Even if `long` and `long long` are the same *size*, they are not the same *type*. What you consider "safe" is in most cases an error. Thus, you need to explicitly tell the compiler that you know what you're doing.

Comment: no `long int` and `long long int` are not the same - they might result in same internal type on current platform, but are, by definition, different types. So to make code -portable- compiler forces developer to be explicit. Please remember that C is sometimes less restrictive than C++.

Comment: @InsideLoop: I think you misunderstand the meaning of "safe" here. The compiler might know what is safe or not *on your platform*, but the reason `static_cast` is not allowed here is because it cannot be considered safe *in the language* (which is, by nature, multiplatform). Because this construct might be illegal, the *language* requires a `static_cast` to fail, and there is nothing the compiler can (or even should) do about it.

Comment: @DevSolar: Thanks for the explanation, I got it. I was expecting a construction that would fail to compile on some platforms (when long int and long long int are different) but not on some others. I understand now that C++ being "multiplatform" does not allow you that.

Comment: @InsideLoop: Well, there *is* a construct doing just that -- `static_assert`. It's just that `static_cast` isn't it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in a portable way with extra storage:

```
long* ptr = /***/;
long long extra_storage = *ptr;
long long* long_ptr = &extra_storage;
```

Without extra storage, but with compile-time check:

```
static_assert(sizeof(long) == sizeof(long long));
long* ptr = /***/;
long long* long_ptr = reinterpret_cast<long long*>(ptr);
```

Comment: In your first example, `long_ptr` is the _address_ of the `extra_storage` variable, not its value.

Comment: @DarkDust That is true.